# Django email attachment filetype limit

Tags: django, django-forms, django-file-upload

How can I limit the type of files of the email attachments sent by my contact form to Doc, Docx, PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/977/) for that.

Usage is:

```
attachment = ExtFileField(ext_whitelist=(".pdf", ".txt"))
```